# Java GUI: repaint() or class interaction issue

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface, repaint

So I'm creating a turtle graphics project and I'm having trouble getting the turtle to move when given command inputs. Below are the two interacting classes, my TextPanel class which handles user input and GraphicsPanel which contains the draw-able 'canvas' etc..

As I'm not getting any errors at the moment I'm wondering if I'm correctly calling the GraphicsPanel class or I'm using repaint() and it's the wrong method? I'm at a loss and could use a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks for your time.

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTextField commField;
private JButton enterBut;
private TextListener textListener;
private GraphicsPanel graphicsPanel;

//***********//
//CONSTRUCTOR//
//***********//

public TextPanel() {

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane ( textArea );
    enterBut = new JButton("Execute");
    commField = new JTextField(10);
    graphicsPanel = new GraphicsPanel();


    textArea.setLineWrap(true);         //stops text from going outside
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);    //panel boundaries

    //**********************//
    //COMMAND IMPLEMENTATION//
    //**********************//

    commField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(commField.getText().contains("penup")) {
                GraphicsPanel.penUp();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("pendown")) {
                GraphicsPanel.penDown();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("turnright")) {
                GraphicsPanel.turnRight();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("turnleft")) {
                GraphicsPanel.turnLeft();
            }
            else if(commField.getText().startsWith("forward")) {        //getText method retrives user input from JTextField
                String cForward = commField.getText();                  //<startsWith> searches string for desired command
                String[] cForwardArray = cForward.split("\\s+");        //string array created and split with " " as split
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cForwardArray[1]);  //parseInt takes the integer from string split
                    GraphicsPanel.forward(distance);                    //GraphicsPanel command called + distance integer
                    textArea.append(cForward + "\n");           //test for variable values
                    GraphicsPanel.validate();
                    GraphicsPanel.repaint();                            //canvas is repainted 


                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }
            else if(commField.getText().startsWith("backward")) {
                String cBackward = commField.getText();
                String[] cBackwardArray = cBackward.split("\\s+");
                try {
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(cBackwardArray[1]);
                    GraphicsPanel.backward(distance);
                    textArea.append(cBackward +"\n");
                    GraphicsPanel.repaint();
                } 
                catch (Exception ev) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, 
                            "Invaild or missing parameter, check the help section\n"
                            + "for more information on Commands");
                }
            }

            else if(commField.getText().contains("black")) {
                GraphicsPanel.black(Color.black);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("green")) {
                GraphicsPanel.green(Color.green);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("red")) {
                GraphicsPanel.red(Color.red);
            }
            else if(commField.getText().contains("reset")) {
                GraphicsPanel.clear();
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textArea, "Invalid command, try again");
            }

            commField.setText("");
            GraphicsPanel.repaint();


        }
    });


    //****************//
    //PANEL DIMENSIONS//
    //****************//

    setBackground(Color.black);

    Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();     //sets dimensions of panel
    dim.width = 250;
    setPreferredSize(dim);

    //setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter Commands here: "));
    //setTitleColor(Color.white); //not sure why this doesnt change the text colour


    //**************//
    //GRIDBAG LAYOUT//
    //**************//

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

    add(commField, constraint);

    constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraint.ipady = 20;
    constraint.ipadx = 60;
    constraint.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 0, 0);
    constraint.weightx = 1;
    constraint.weighty = 0;
    constraint.gridx = 0;                           //grid position
    constraint.gridy = 0;

    add(commField, constraint);
    //***********************//

    constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraint.ipady = 15;
    constraint.ipadx = 25;
    constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;    //anchors to bottom of GUI
    constraint.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);        //inserts gap
    constraint.weightx = 0;
    constraint.weighty = 0;
    constraint.gridx = 1;                       
    constraint.gridy = 0;

    add(enterBut, constraint);

    //*************************//

    constraint.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;      //option how to fill 'cell' 
    constraint.ipady = 150;                         //dim of component 
    constraint.ipadx = 150;
    constraint.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 0);
    constraint.gridwidth = 3;                       //how many grid cell it spans
    constraint.weightx = 1;                         //precedent for space
    constraint.weighty = 1;
    constraint.gridx = 0;                           //grid position
    constraint.gridy = 1;

    add(new JScrollPane(textArea), constraint);                     //adds component
                                                                    //and JSCrollPane
    //************************//

    //**NOTES****************************//
    //next time use smaller variable name//
    //***********************************//

}


private void setTitleColor(Color white) {


}

public void appendText(String text) {

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}

public void setTextListener(textListener listener) {
    this.TextListener = listener;
}
}
```

This is my GraphicsPanel class containing the command functions and JPanel set up including bufferedimage etc..

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")                     //Represents the graphics display panel
                                                //panel within the turtle program. 
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {     //This panel contains an image which 
                                                //is updated to reflect user commands.



//background colour image



private final static Color BACKGROUND_COL = Color.DARK_GRAY;
private final static int TURTLE_X_SIZE = 20, TURTLE_Y_SIZE = 20;

private TextPanel TextPanel;
//private JTextField getTextField();

private BufferedImage image, turtleDisplay;     //The underlying image used 
                                                //for drawing. This is required


//Djm added
private Color PenColour = Color.GREEN;          //so any previous drawing activity is 
private boolean penDown = false;                //is persistent on the panel.
private int xPos=325, yPos=180;
private int direction = 180;                    //robot pointing down the screen;




//change drawLine colour

public void black(Color color) {
    color = Color.black;
}

public void green(Color color) {
    color = Color.green;
}

public void red(Color color) {
    color = Color.red;
}

public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(color);
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}


public void penDown() {
    penDown = true;
}

//***********************************//

public void penUp() {
    penDown = false;
}

//***********************************//

public void turnRight() {
    direction +=90;
    if (direction >= 360)
        direction = 0;
}

//***********************************//

public void turnLeft() {
    direction -=90;
    if (direction < 0)
        direction = 270;
}

//***********************************//


//sends the turtle forward

public void forward(int distance) {
                                    //Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    int x=xPos,y=yPos;
                                    //stored xPos and yPos are current location

    if (direction == 0) {           //robot facing up the screen, so forward subtracts y
        y = yPos-distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 90) {     //robot facing right so forward add x
        x = xPos + distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 180) {     //robot facing down the screen, so forwards adds to y
        y = yPos + distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 270) {    //robot facing left, so forwards subtracts from x
        x = xPos - distance;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("strange, shouldn't get here");
    }
    if (penDown) {
                                            //x=400; y=400;
        drawLine(PenColour, xPos, yPos, x, y);
                                            //g.drawLine(xPos,yPos,x,y);
    }
                                            //now robot has moved to the new position
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}

//***********************************//

//sends the turtle backwards

public void backward(int distance) {

    int x=xPos,y=yPos;
    //stored xPos and yPos are current location

    if (direction == 0) {           //robot facing up the screen, so forward adds y
        y = yPos + distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 90) {     //robot facing right so forward subtract x
        x = xPos - distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 180) {     //robot facing down the screen, so forwards subtracts to y
        y = yPos - distance;
    }
    else if (direction == 270) {    //robot facing left, so forwards adds from x
        x = xPos + distance;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("strange, shouldn't get here");
    }
    if (penDown) {
                                                            //x=400; y=400;
        drawLine(PenColour, xPos, yPos, x, y);
                                                            //g.drawLine(xPos,yPos,x,y);
    }
                                                            //now robot has moved to the new position
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;

}

//***********************************//

 //Clears the image contents.

public void clear() {

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(BACKGROUND_COL);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(),  image.getHeight());
}

//***********************************//


public void setTurtleColour(Color col) {
    Graphics g = turtleDisplay.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(col);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, turtleDisplay.getWidth(),  turtleDisplay.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{


    super.paintComponent(g);

    // render the image on the panel.
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(turtleDisplay, xPos-TURTLE_X_SIZE/2, yPos-TURTLE_Y_SIZE/2, null);

}



//***********//
//CONSTRUCTOR//
//***********//

public GraphicsPanel() {

    //main drawing area
    image = new BufferedImage(650, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


    //small image to display on top of drawing area to represent the turtle
    turtleDisplay =  new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //set up turtle
    setTurtleColour(PenColour);

    // Set max size of the panel, so that is matches the max size of the image.
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    setSize(800,400);
    setVisible(true);

    clear();
}
```

}

Comment: Class names SOULD start with upper case characters. Variable names SHOULD NOT start with upper case characters (except your static variable names, which are correct). This affects the highlighting of the code in the forum, making your code difficult to read. Fix and repost your code.

Comment: Where the code that updates the turtle coordinates and call repaint()?

Comment: `on a side note:` - that is a different issue and there are plenty of example in the forum on how to draw a background image. Keep the topic to a single question.

Comment: Why would you be using a text field for commands? Users will get tired of typing and making mistakes or wondering what the valid set of commands are. Use buttons for each command, or maybe a combo box with a list of the valid commands.

Comment: I made the edits to change the naming protocols, oops. @camickr I do have a toolbar with buttons set up, but part of my assignment is having the ability to enter text commands too which, yes is pretty redundant.

Comment: @camickr Concerning the coordinates ..i thought it was located in Override public void paintComponent I haven't called repaint() there though. Hmm

Comment: `I haven't called repaint() there though` - you would NEVER call repaint() from the paintComponent() method. You call repaint() when you change a property of your component. So for example you need to add repaint() to methods like: "penUp(), penDown(), turnRight()...". Basically any method you invoked from your ActionListeners should contain repaint() so the panel is repainted with the new properties.